# Marklogic 9: MLCP fails when importing records with a transform

Tags: marklogic, mlcp, marklogic-9

I'm trying to migrate one of my dev envts from ML8 to ML9. I have an import script that successfully works on the ML8 version, but there's an error when I try running it against the ML9 database. The ML9 version is 9.0.3.1. The MLCP version is 9.0.3

My MLCP options file is as follows:

```
import
-host 
192.168.33.10
-port 
8041
-username 
admin
-password
admin
-input_file_path 
d:\maroon\data\mbastest.csv 
-mode 
local 
-input_file_type 
delimited_text 
-uri_id 
ClientId 
-output_uri_prefix
/test/records/
-output_uri_suffix 
.json 
-document_type 
json 
-transform_module 
/ingestion/transform.js
-transform_function 
testTransform
-transform_param
test
-content_encoding 
windows-1252 
-thread_count
1
```

Here's the output of a test run with only 2 records in the test CSV file:

```
17/10/30 14:07:33 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: JSON
17/10/30 14:07:33 INFO contentpump.ContentPump: Job name: local_455168344_1
17/10/30 14:07:33 INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
17/10/30 14:07:38 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: Failed document /test/records/31.json
17/10/30 14:07:38 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: <error:format-string xmlns:error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_, expecting $end or SemiColon_</error:format-string>
17/10/30 14:07:38 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: Failed document /test/records/32.json
17/10/30 14:07:38 WARN contentpump.TransformWriter: <error:format-string xmlns:error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_, expecting $end or SemiColon_</error:format-string>
17/10/30 14:07:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 100%
17/10/30 14:07:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicCounter:
17/10/30 14:07:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: INPUT_RECORDS: 2
17/10/30 14:07:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS: 2
17/10/30 14:07:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS_COMMITTED: 0
17/10/30 14:07:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: OUTPUT_RECORDS_FAILED: 2
17/10/30 14:07:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Total execution time: 5 sec
```

If I remove the transform params, the import works fine.

I thought it might be a parsing issue with my transform module itself, so I tried replacing it with the following example from the documentation:

```
// Add a property named "NEWPROP" to any JSON input document.
// Otherwise, input passes through unchanged.

function addProp(content, context)
{
  const propVal = (context.transform_param == undefined)
                 ? "UNDEFINED" : context.transform_param;

  if (xdmp.nodeKind(content.value) == 'document' &&
      content.value.documentFormat == 'JSON') {
    // Convert input to mutable object and add new property
    const newDoc = content.value.toObject();
    newDoc.NEWPROP = propVal;

    // Convert result back into a document
    content.value = xdmp.unquote(xdmp.quote(newDoc));
  }
  return content;
};

exports.addProp = addProp;
```

(Of course I changed the params in the MLCP options file accordingly)

The issue still persists even with just this test function.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm running the same versions and I haven't received any errors on my system - and the example addProp() function works as expected as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the issue is because the extension of the transform module is .js. If I change it to .sjs, the MLCP import proceeds as expected.